# Minimal sum of values in table to exceed specific amount

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do something that really get me stuck. It sounds simple in plain English.

I have this Mysql table:

```
ITEMS

+--Item--+--Amount--+--Price--+
Apple         3          6
Pear          2          5
```

And I want to know how many of these I need to sell to obtain the minimum possible sum that exceeds let say $16.5. The output should be: 2 apples + 1 pear = $17.

I've tried to figure out something with arrays and min(function), but have not actually got even close to it.

Anyone could enlighten a bit here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what you even tried?

Comment: @Ankit_Sharma, I have tried lousy things not worth showing.

Comment: This could mean "nothing"

Comment: I'd try dividing by the largest price (lower than your target price) into your target price, and then trying the next lower nearest priced item into the remainder and so on (taking stock into account).

Comment: @chancar Do you have only two items or items count can be different?

Comment: @Zhorov, items count can be different. Just showed 2 in the example to avoid displaying useless data.

Comment: You must sell all the items?

Comment: @McBern, no it just have to sell the minimum neccessary items to get money to pay a specific amount ($17 in my example above)

Comment: what if there are multiple solutions ? Say if the target is `30$`, you could sell 5 apples (6$/piece) or 6 pears (5$/piece)

Comment: @GMB there is no requirement for that, but I think a good approach is that it performs the sale that requires selling less items (in this case, selling 5 apples).

Comment: Do the items and their prices change over time or are they staying constant?

Comment: @Jannes Botis they change over time indeed.